# Is there any difference between upper or lower case commands on SQLITE?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqlite.swift

My question is if there's any performance difference between:

`SELECT * FROM mytable`

vs

`select * from mytable`

yes, the whole question is about using reserved words in upper case for better legibility

Comment: No difference at all.  Identifiers are case-insensitive in SQL.

Comment: Same thing. (Back in the days, ANSI entry level SQL-92 required upper case keywords, but AFAIK no vendor had that restriction.)